# Confluent Kafka Close() method commits offsets

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I use Confluent Kafka .NET library. If to follow the documentation for `IConsumer` `Close()` method:

> Commits offsets, alerts the group coodinator  that the consumer is
>   exiting the group then  releases all resources used by this consumer.
>   You should call Close
>   instead of Dispose (or
>   just before) to ensure a timely consumergroup rebalance

In my case, `autocommit` is set to `false`. I want to simply crash the application if I failed to process the message, and I **do not** want to commit the offset.

My question is:

if I'm going to use `Close()` method when exiting the application(which is obviously important your consumer be able to rebalance) is it going to commit the offset when `autocommit` set to `false` or not? Or it's only valid if `autocommit` is set to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

you can look in the source code the [Close()](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/348c4e34bb996ea0d49e6de71445a28181ccfcfc/src/Confluent.Kafka/Consumer.cs#L558) function:

```
 public void Close()
    {
        **// commits offsets and unsubscribes.**
        kafkaHandle.ConsumerClose();
        if (this.handlerException != null)
        {
            var ex = this.handlerException;
            this.handlerException = null;
            throw ex;
        }

        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

so, the Close() function call to kafkaHandle.ConsumerClose() and Dispose(true):
[SafeKafkaHandle::kafkaHandle.ConsumerClose():](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Impl/SafeKafkaHandle.cs#L727)

```
internal void ConsumerClose()
    {
        ThrowIfHandleClosed();
        
        ErrorCode err = **Librdkafka.consumer_close(handle);**
        if (err != ErrorCode.NoError)
        {
            throw new KafkaException(CreatePossiblyFatalError(err, null));
        }
    }
```

[Librdkafka.consumer_close](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/src/rdkafka.h#L3857):

```
* @remark This call will block until the consumer has revoked its assignment,
      calling the \c rebalance_cb if it is configured, committed offsets
      to broker, and left the consumer group.
      The maximum blocking time is roughly limited to session.timeout.ms.
```

so, yes. Close() function call to commit even you configured as autoOffset=false. [maybe I'm wrong in special cases, there is this [flag](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/src/rdkafka.h#L2838) ]

what about the Dispose()?
we go to the grandfather base of SafeKafkaHandle : SafeHandleZeroIsInvalid : SafeHandle. SafeHandle is [Microsoft class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=net-5.0), so there is no chance there is some kafka handle there.

so, it look the "correct way" is to call to Close() in the consumer destructor, but if you want exit without commit, call just to Dispose().

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit easier soultion to this issue is to leave `EnableAutoCommit` set to `true` and instead set [`EnableAutoOffsetStore`](https://_sgpConsumer.StoreOffset(message);) to `false`. This will prevent the auto commit to automatically commit offsets of consumed messages.

Instead you need to **manually save offsets to the offset store** which will then be picked up and auto committed. After you process a message you can save offsets to the store by invoking the `StoreOffset` method on the consumer object.

```
consumer.StoreOffset(consumeResult);
```

or

```
consumer.StoreOffset(topicPartitionOffset);
```

In that way you can still use `Close()` upon exiting the application and you don't need to worry about manually commiting offsets. This approach can also be used if you need manual control of the commit process.